# MVC Entity framework says that field is NULL but it's not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create new object and add it to DB. First I set unique ID to Product (my entity). And return the view where user can set other fields.

```
     public ViewResult Create()
     {
         var product = new Product { ProductID = GetFreeId() };    
         return View("Edit",product);
     }
```

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.EditorForModel()
<input type="submit" value="Save" />}
```

Then through controller we come to this method:

```
public void AddProduct(Product product)
{
     context.Products.Add(product);   
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If i put a breakpoint at the last method I will see `product.ProductID=10` but on the `string context.SaveChanges();` i get exception:

> can not insert the entity with ProductID=null.

Where is the error?

Comment: just wondering you coming back to AddProduct actionresult?

Comment: Yes.    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.AddProduct(product);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to supply the keys manually and the key isn't an autogenerated identity in the database you must tell this to Entity Framework, for example with data annotations in your `Product` model:

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

With Fluent API it is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.ProductID)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

The default for `int` keys is that EF assumes that the ID is generated in the database and EF won't send the ID value to the DB, even if it is set in your model. The database throws an exception then because it doesn't get a key in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank u! What type should I set to ProductID instead of int to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Stalli: For `string` and `Guid`, I believe, the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` is `None` by default. But I would leave it an `int` and just override the default as shown above. There is the option to override the default, there is nothing wrong to use this option.

Answer (score 0):

Likely when you post back the ID isn't set. You should set it in the post method.